# Should all variables in a VAR model have the same number of lags?

Tags: vector-autoregression, lags

I'm performing an econometric analysis and all my variables (in daily frequency) are stationary, so I've decided to use a VAR model. After analyzing the data in Stata, it suggests all variables should have a lag of 1 day except one (let's call it Z), which should have a lag of 4 days.

When constructing the model, should I:

1. Lag every variable up to 4 lags?
2. Lag every variable once and variable Z until lag 4?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for the different variables in a VAR model to have the same number of lags. I am not sure how you decided that 1 and 4 lags were optimal, but if that was a sound procedure then go with it (option 2).